# Finding in a std map using regex

Tags: c++, regex, boost, stl

I want to know how I can look up for an item in a map using a regex function. In my case, I have a **map** with expressions such as en*, es*, en-AU and so on and I have a **string** of possible values like en, en-US, en-GB, es-CL and so on.

I want to search using that **string** to find that item in the **map**.
Looking for the key without the wildcard first then looking for the key with the wildcard as the 2nd priority.

Please help me out with this problem or if this is an inefficient or if any one has a different approach please tell me another method for that. I use C++ with boost and stl.

Comment: Do you mean you have *keys* in the map that you want to search for using regex, or that you have *values* in the map that you want to search for?

Comment: Either way, you have to manually iterate over all keys/values and do the search for each key/value.

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. You may want to read the "[how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice)" faq to help you pose your question so as to help us help you.

Comment: Expressions like `en*`, `es*` look like wildcards, not regexp. The equivalent regexps would be `^en.*`, `^es.*`.

Comment: By map do you mean `std::map` or any associative container?  Is general wildcards required, or only that exact pattern of wildcards?  Do you have control over how the container is defined?  How many entries are we talking about -- 10, 1000, 100000, 10000000, 1000000000, more?

Comment: The type used in a map needs a well defined less than operator.  Is "en*" less than "en-AU" or not?

Answer (score 8):

If the map is small or the search is executed rarely, then just iterate through the map and match each key with the regular expression.

Otherwise: If the *regular expression* is used only for some kind of prefix search, you can use the member function `lower_bound` to efficiently find all entries with the given prefix. For example the following function first looks for an entry that matches exactly. If no such entry exists, the function returns the range of all entries with a matching prefix.

```
using items = std::map<std::string, item>;

auto lookup(const items& items, const std::string& key)
    -> std::pair<items::const_iterator, items::const_iterator>
{
    auto p = items.lower_bound(key);
    auto q = items.end();
    if (p != q && p->first == key) {
        return std::make_pair(p, std::next(p));
    } else {
        auto r = p;
        while (r != q && r->first.compare(0, key.size(), key) == 0) {
            ++r;
        }
        return std::make_pair(p, r);
    }
}
```

Otherwise: If you have to cope with *regular expressions* or *wildcards*, then you can combine the two approaches. First search for an entry that matches exactly with the member function `find`. If no such entry exists, then extract the constant prefix from the regular expression. The prefix may be empty. Use the member function `lower_bound` to find the first entry with that prefix. Iterate through all entries with that prefix and test if the regular expression matches.